# Validation works but does not keep the selected div open

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a  Save call this JavaScript

`submit('formName',null,{Method:'Post'});` - Basically `null` should contain the `divname` when validation fails, it should point to that div

The above is working, but when the validation fails it moves to the first tab, i want it to stay in the open tab by passing the divname to this submit form

i have this code to validate and get the divname of the failed validation form field

```
function AClick(ic) {
            if($("#divSubFeature_" + ic).is(':visible')) {
                alert("aa");
                //$("#divSubFeature_" + ic).css('display','block');
            }
        }
```

so not sure how i pass the divname to the submit function so it keeps that tab open

any idea?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ztLpywmr/ - not exactly the same but somewhat near

Comment: what tab? i don't see tabs in your code. why you don't use a submit button instead a link outside of the form?

Comment: its an old application build like this, can't change its structure

Comment: UI tabs are being used